# selector show element and context. Cannot get the element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Maybe this is a very stupid question, but not stupid enough for me since I can't seem to figure this out (even with Google).

I have this jquery:

```
$.each(items, function (key, t) {
  $("#list").append(
    $("<li />")
     .append($("<img />")
       .attr("src", "path/to/" + t.Thumbnail)
       .addClass("thumb"))
       .append($("<span />")
         .html("<b>" + t.Title + "</b><br />" + t.Description)));
});
```

After this I loop through the thumbs to do some styling (with size and ratio, not relevant here)

```
$(".thumb").each(function () {
  console.log($(this));
});
```

In the console I see this:

```
[img.thumb, context: img.thumb, jquery: "1.9.0", constructor: function, init: function,     
selector: ""…]
0: img.thumb
context: img.thumb
length: 1
__proto__: Object[0]
```

What is this context? With $(this).width() it gives an error or 0. When I have an image that is already on the page it just...works?!

So, the problem is: Why doesn't this work and why does it work on other pages?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
Added an example to Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nN9ce/

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: Or even copy and past what the error is.

Comment: When you use a selector `$('.thumb')` it traverses the entire `DOM` to find the particular selector.. But if you pass in a context it will only try to find that element in that particular `context`  .. So if you write the same selector as `$('.thumb', 'table')` it will only try to find the elements within the `table` elements and not the entire `DOM`

Comment: @Sushanth ... Tried that... Didn't work. When you do $(".thumb").width() it gives 0... when this should be 240 pixels. Same with your example/suggestion

Comment: It looks like you're trying to read the width before the image has finished loading. When I run it the first time I get zero, but if I reload I get 128 since it pulls it from the cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.width()` gets the size of the element, and not the image itself.  When the script runs, although the images have been added to the dom, they aren't loaded yet so the elements have a width of 0 (even if the images you are about to load into those elements are of width 128).

You need to run a callback after the images are loaded.

Comment: Makes sense... Somehow :) I'll try that

Comment: This may or may not be useful! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached

Comment: Hero! :)
I've updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nN9ce/3/ It's finaly working! Well... Was very easy, stupid to miss this. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah you should always remember that JQuery only works with DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the width and height attributes on the images. Try making this change:

```
.attr("src", "http://www.logoquizantwoorden.nl/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Logo-Quiz-uitleg.png")
.attr("height", "128")
.attr("width", "128")
.addClass("thumb")
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sBSnS/

Comment: That's whole point: Get the actual size of the image, not a defined size. I need to play with the size, but keep the ratio

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about the method problem but you can use the property

```
width
```

So, you'd have this.

```
$(".thumb").each(function () {
    console.log(this.width);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
$(".thumb").each(function (idx, thumb) {
  console.log($(thumb)); 
   console.log($(thumb).width());
});
```

Here is updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nN9ce/2/

Comment: You're making the same mistake a few others have made. Clear your cache and run your fiddle. You get zero the first time and a value the times after that because the images are coming from the cache.

Comment: Cache was not the bad guy... This time. See the answer I selected. I needed to wait on the image to load

Comment: Totally true ! Sorry... Read the question AND the code badly... blaming bad sleep the latest two nights :) ...

Comment: LOL no problem... Same here, that's why I had this problem :)